# scraping table with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table that is under a div tag with id pcaxis_tablediv using the following code. However, when I am printing it, it returns None. I am looking at the source code of the website and I can't see what am I doing wrong.

```
url='https://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/sv/ssd/START__AM__AM0208__AM0208B/YREG65/sortedtable/tableViewSorted/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
wanted_table = soup.find_all('div', id="pcaxis_tablediv")
print(wanted_table)
```

Comment: There are no divs with that id that are in the source. Which is probably why it's returning None

Comment: can't you just use their api or are you just practicing your skills: https://www.scb.se/api/

Comment: @Gregor Not everyone is comfortable with `json` which is usually the format. If it is nested dicts..the OP will keep asking questions for a week. :)